# Function to test the result of difference of two ranges in excel VBA

Tags: function, excel, vba

Hi I am new to excel VBA.
I need to take two ranges of time in cells as:
6:00   7:00   8:00...
and 
6:20:  7:34   8:50...
I want to test each of the corresponding cells against a difference of 30 mins(such as 6:00 with 6:20 and 7:00 with 7:34) and calculate the number of time the value is greater than 30 mins.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Im not sure what you want to do. Show your code? I asume just use simple equation with IF worksheet function will help you. Reason to use VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a worksheet formula.

Eg:

```
 =SUM(IF(C2:C8-B2:B8>TIME(0,30,0),1,0))
```

entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter